# Can't send mail with Postfix and mutt

Tags: postfix, mutt

I have a problem with Postfix and mutt. When I try to send an email the following message is logged:

```
"May 30 11:12:30 alarmasyslog postfix/smtp[22143]: 4A5421801815: to=<xxxxxxx@enterprise.cl>, relay=164.77.252.208[164.77.252.208]:25, delay=64203, delays=64203/0.06/0.03/0.06, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host 164.77.252.208[164.77.252.208] said: 450 4.1.8 <root@xdomainx.xxx.net>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))"
```

How can I configure Postfix or mutt to solve this?

Comment: The problem would not seem to be at your end with Postfix and mutt.  The error message says that the receiving box can't find the domain of the sending box: either at all or in the list of domains not thought to be e-mail spammers.  It's often a problem if the sending box doesn't even have a domain name; just an ip address.  In these sad times you have to clear a lot of hurdles to get your e-mail delivered but what those hurdles are is another question entirely and one that you might take up with the e-mail admin for the receiving box or for the network that it's in.

Comment: Can you tell me what to check o change in the configuration files.. what do I need to get this work.. Thank!!

Comment: Well, if your sending box _has_ a valid (not on any spam-block list) domain already set up then the answer below re: _/etc/Muttrc should let the complaining receiver deal with your e-mail.  If you don't have registered domain for this box ,ie. it's just a benchtop box with an ip address, then you have to get one or get the receiving box to somehow like you anyway.  In either of those cases the problem is quite different from your question as it is outside of <i>Postfix</i> and <i>mutt</i>: indeed it is entirely outside of your box.

Answer (score 0):

The domain is not found. 
That is, Postfix can't resolve MX register of domain of sender.

You have to configure Mutt, with your correct sender address (/etc/Muttrc, I think).

Comment: The domain is configure in the '..main.conf' file of Postfix. 
How can I configure mutt to set the correct sender..?